# Inkscape: remove stroke preserve size/shape

Tags: inkscape

I've created a path with a stroke and a fill of the same color, and I'd like to remove the stroke while preserving the size/shape of the object. Is there a simple way to do this?

In other words, I'm looking for something like a "Stroke-and-Fill to Path"

The best solution that I have come up with so far is to use "Stroke To Path" and then delete all of the inner nodes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An alternative to DA01's answer:

1. Select an object.
2. Convert selected object's stroke to paths (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).
3. Break apart the path (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>).
4. Delete the inside path by clicking somewhere outside, then clicking in the center and deleting.

[image]

Comment: That's actually a better alternative! Saves a few steps. Good tip!

Comment: What a life-saver! You can also use this to preserve a transparent outline for two adjacent objects - if you delete the outer path. Great!

Answer (score 16):

> The best solution that I have come up with so far is to use "Stroke To Path" and then delete all of the inner nodes.

Yep. That's how you do it.

If you want to save a bit of time, you could do this:

- Select object
- EDIT > DUPLICATE
- select this duplicate and remove the stroke
- deselect the duplicate object on top and select the original below
- PATH > STROKE TO PATH
- now select both items together and PATH > UNION

That will save you the step of having to delete the inner nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but if you don't need too much precision you can just take the path with stroke and click in it with the paint bucket tool (you may set a little bigger stroke on the path). I sometimes use this stupid trick with letters or logos, becouse the union-method explained above often leaves nodes and imperfections in the final path.

Still in need for a specific tool (it would be useful).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

select erasing existing paths tool and aply it just on the border you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

1) select the object by "edit paths by nodes (F2)". it is 2nd item on left.

2) CTRL+X / Cut

3) Again select the object

4) Go to Object -> Fill and Stroke

Now you won't have white borders when you color the object.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to copy or memorize the objects x dimension, remove the stroke, then enter the dimension you want back in.  (Don't forget to ✔️ proportional)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to export the image as a PNG. Import that PNG, then do a trace bitmap on it & voila...one solid SVG at the size you want it.