# In Inkscape, what's to quickest way to combine an object's stroke and fill to an unstroked object?

Tags: inkscape

I'm using fat, rounded strokes to create objects with rounded corners. I've been combining, using Union, an unstroked version of my object with the results of 'Stroke to Path' but it seems like there must be a quicker way. What's the most direct way to go from A to B?

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention this question applies to Inkscape.

[image]

Comment: This question as already been asked evidently. Different wording but same desired outcome, and the #1 answer is what I'm already doing. 
LINK: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/inkscape-remove-stroke-preserve-size-shape?rq=1

Comment: I'm going to close this question, it has been adequately answered here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/inkscape-remove-stroke-preserve-size-shape?rq=1 For my uses, the answer beginning with "An alternative to DA01's answer...", currently answer #2, is the most elegant solution.